# How to fix illegal start of expression compilation error?

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method that takes a 2D array of integers as an argument. The array returns a new 2D array
of integers of the same size (same number of rows and columns). The values in the returned array are the same
as those in the argument array EXCEPT that any negative values are made positive.

My method will not compile the compiler keeps complaining about my method that its illegal start of expression. It appears to fails to recognize that I have written a method whats so ever.

This is what I have done:

```
public class Examprep1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int [][] array = new int[2][4];
        array[0][0]=1;
        array[0][1]=5;
        array[0][2]=-7;
        array[0][3]=9;
        array[1][0]=-2;
        array[1][1]=4;
        array[1][2]=6;
        array[1][3]=-8;

        int x;

        // Using for loops to create the 2D array
        for (int rows=0; rows<2; rows++)
        {
            for (int cols=0; cols<4;cols++)
            {
                System.out.print( array[rows][cols]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println(newArray(array));

        private static int[][] newArray(int[][] old)
        {
            int y;
            int[][] current = new int [2][4];

            for (int rows=0; rows<2; rows++)
            {
                for (int cols=0; cols<4;cols++)
                {   
                    if (old[rows][cols]<0)
                    {
                        y=Math.abs(old[rows][cols]);
                        old[rows][cols] = (int)Math.pow(old[rows][cols],2)/x;
                    }
                    old[rows][cols] = current[rows][cols];
                 }  
            }
            return current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` after `System.out.println(newArray(array));` to end `main`. You need to do that *before* you can declare `newArray`. Then you have an extra closing `}` after `newArray`. Finally, where did `x` come from in `old[rows][cols] = (int)Math.pow(old[rows][cols],2)/x;`?

Comment: You defined a method within a method. You cannot do that

Comment: You shouldn't rely that `current = new int [2][4]` if this method is supposed to always be the same size as the input. It is also very unclear why you are squaring numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are lot of compilation issue. You should starting writing code step by step.

Here is the working model: (Advice you for reference)

```
class Examprep1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[2][4];
        array[0][0] = 1;
        array[0][1] = 5;
        array[0][2] = -7;
        array[0][3] = 9;
        array[1][0] = -2;
        array[1][1] = 4;
        array[1][2] = 6;
        array[1][3] = -8;

        int x = 0;

        // Using for loops to create the 2D array
        System.out.println("Printing old array");
        printArray(array);

        System.out.println("Printing new  array");
        printArray(newArray(array, x));

    }

    private static void printArray(int[][] a) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++) {
            for (int cols = 0; cols < 4; cols++) {

                System.out.print(a[rows][cols] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

    private static int[][] newArray(int[][] old, int x) {
        int y;
        int[][] current = new int[2][4];

        for (int rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++) {
            for (int cols = 0; cols < 4; cols++) {

                y = Math.abs(old[rows][cols]);
                current[rows][cols] = y;

            }

        }
        return current;
    }

}
```

Comment: wow its amazing how it only took you a few moments to fix my code. Hopefully one day I will be just as good....I have a feeling that will take a long...long time.Thanks a whole bunch. I'm presently going through your code to see what exactly I did wrong.Have a great weekend.

Comment: You had a good understanding of things.. Just place things at write place. Start with small piece of code. Keep debugging by printing intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have greatly over-complicated your implementation. You can declare and initialize a 2D array one line. You can also use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) to print your 2D arrays. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = { { 1, 5, -7, 9 }, { -2, 4, 6, -8 } };
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newArray(array)));
} //<-- remember to close main.
```

Then you could use [`Object.clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) to copy your `old` array. Iterate the array, and set the current value to the `Math.abs(int)`. Like,

```
private static int[][] newArray(int[][] old) {
    int[][] current = old.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < current[i].length; j++) {
            current[i][j] = Math.abs(current[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Which outputs

```
[[1, 5, -7, 9], [-2, 4, 6, -8]]
[[1, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you Elliott for all the great tips. I had no idea old.clone() existed. I am pretty sure my textbook is trying to ruin my life. Every process is in there is overly complicated. Anyway, you really helped  out.Have a great weekend.